# Using Eclipse for Web Applications

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, google-app-engine, osx-tiger

I'm running Eclipse and trying to follow the steps written here for using the Google App Engine.

I've pasted what's in the console when I *debug as web application*.  On [google's](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html) site I've been following the steps.  But then when I go to localhost:8888/xxxxxx  I get an error.

Please advise.  I'm running Java 1.5 and on Mac OSX Tiger and Eclipse is Ganymede.

Thanks.

```
    2011-04-16 09:41:49.967 java[257] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
    2011-04-16 09:41:49.968 java[257] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
    ********************************************************
    Warning: Future versions of the Dev App Server will require Java 1.6 or later. Please upgrade your JRE.
    ********************************************************
    Apr 15, 2011 9:41:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
    Apr 15, 2011 9:41:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
    INFO: Successfully processed /Users/kateswanson/Documents/workspace/AppEngineInterview/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
    Apr 15, 2011 9:41:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
    INFO: Successfully processed /Users/kateswanson/Documents/workspace/AppEngineInterview/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: Besides the warning about using java 1.6 instead of 1.5 is there an actual error message with a stacktrace that is produced?  I don't see an actaul errors in your post.

Comment: Agreed with other comments here; why aren't you using a Java 6 JDK?

Comment: @Matt Ball I can't find Java 6 JDK for Mac OS Tiger

Comment: @hooknc I don't know where to find those errors.

Comment: ...Tiger? Wow, that is _old_ (6 years old, at the end of the month).  As of 2009-08-28, Apple dropped official support for Tiger. **It is time to upgrade,** amigo.

Answer (score 1):

It's only about your java version it have to be Java 1.6.

Just upgrade your java version and it's will works fine..

Good Luck